# can't load package: package .: cannot find package "." in

Tags: go, path, package, load, directory

I have two folders projects with Golang projects. In the first all projects works, but in the other a have "can't load package: package .: cannot find package "."" in all projects.

1. E:/Clouds/hubiC/GoLang/test/test.go
2. E:/Clouds/OneDrive/CX/GoLang/test/test.go

With the same code...

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hi")
    return
}
```

In the 1... all fine:

> c:/go/bin/go.exe build -i [E:/Clouds/hubiC/GoLang/test]
>   Success: process exited with code 0.

In the 2... :S

> c:/go/bin/go.exe build -i [E:/Clouds/OneDrive/CX/GoLang/test] can't
>   load package: package .: cannot find package "." in:
>     E:\Clouds\OneDrive\CX\GoLang\test Error: process exited with code 1.

Why happend this?

I am using

> go version go1.10 windows/amd64

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Michael. Its works!

Its a OneDrive error, I cut de folder outside OneDrive, sync, and re-paste in, and its works! :D